# du: how to get size and number of files inside that folder

Tags: disk-usage

I am using `du` to get the file sizes

Is there any option which will show the number of files and folders count inside each folder.

Example:

Here `somefolder` has 5000 files and 10 folders

```
~$   du -ah --max-depth=0 /home/ubuntu/somefolder
515G    /home/ubuntu/somefolder  [show number of files count also]
```

Comment: You could use **tree --du** instead. In any case **man tree** first, there is just a bunch of options that you might find helpful in order to limit the output.

Comment: yes, `tree --du -ha  /some/dir | tail -n 1` would probably be what OP wants

Answer (score -1):

You can to it with the `find` command

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: This finds the total number of files in the directory and all subdirectories. The OP wanted the number of files in each directory.

Comment: This will additionally output the wrong count if any filename contains newlines. Better to just `echo .` for each found thing and count those lines instead.